# Cloudinary Gem Breaking Bootstrap on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, cloudinary

I have a Rails app which has a photo uploading feature. Previously I was using CarrierWave_Direct to upload directly to S3 (based on [Railscast 383](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3)). In order to optimize the app, I went ahead and switched to Cloudinary.

The app currently works locally just fine with Cloudinary. However when I pushed to heroku the app crashes with the server log error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "  font-family: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@altFontFamily;"
2013-09-04T05:16:29.148898+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)):
2013-09-04T05:16:29.148898+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:       <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.1/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
2013-09-04T05:16:29.148898+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     <![endif]-->
2013-09-04T05:16:29.148898+00:00 app[web.1]:     14: 
2013-09-04T05:16:29.148898+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
2013-09-04T05:16:29.148898+00:00 app[web.1]:     16: 
2013-09-04T05:16:29.148898+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:     <!-- For third-generation iPad with high-resolution Retina display: -->
2013-09-04T05:16:29.148898+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:     <!-- Size should be 144 x 144 pixels -->
2013-09-04T05:16:29.149145+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__164934612574999860_69925614481940'
2013-09-04T05:16:29.149145+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-04T05:16:29.149145+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-04T05:16:29.149499+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LandingController#landing as HTML
2013-09-04T05:16:29.149499+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered landing/landing.html.erb within layouts/application (58.3ms)
2013-09-04T05:16:29.149499+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 158ms
```

I reverted back to a previous commit previous to adding Cloudinary (when the app worked, and have isolated the moment when the app starts breaking to when I add the Cloudinary Gem. Even though the error references a css error the app only breaks when I add the Cloudinary Gem.

In the process of trying to figure this out I discovered that when I run heroku run rake I get the error.

> rake aborted! undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

I suspect this is the issue, however the app only breaks when adding the Cloudinary Gem, even though if I run 'heroku run rake' BEFORE adding the gem, I get the same error, yet the app still functions.

Here is what I got when I ran heroku run rake --trace

```
$ heroku run rake --trace
Running `rake --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.1893
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:test:purge
rake aborted!
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:511:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:544:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge
```

Any suggestions are well appreciated.

**EDIT** Adding application.css file.

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
 *= require_tree .
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 */

 input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
 input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
 }
 .form-signin {
        max-width: 300px;
        padding: 19px 29px 29px;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
        opacity: .9;
        border: 5px solid #0367b0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
           -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                text-align: center;
      }
h2.form-signin {
  font-family: @altFontFamily;
}
.landing {
  background: url('baseball_dirt.jpg') no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
  height: 100%;
  padding:120px 0;
}
.signup {
  background: url('homeplate_line.jpg') no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
  height: 100%;
  padding:120px 0;
}
.signip .well {
  opacity: .85;
}
.signin {
  background: url('baseball_dirt.jpg') no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
  height: 100%;
  padding:120px 0;
}
.signin .well {
  opacity: .85;
}
```

Comment: Looks like if I comment out
`    <%#= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>`
the app will function properly on heroku, (aside from there being no styling).

Comment: Can you attach your application.css file? It appears something there is causing the error

Comment: Just EDITED the post. Any insights are MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Even if I comment out the entire application.css file I still get the error.

Comment: The error you reported is for a line in your application.css, what is the error you are getting when the file is commented out? BTW @altFontFamily is LESS syntax. Make sure the file is called application.css.less

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I jumped back to my previous commit and tried your suggestion with the Cloudinary Gem but still got the same error.

Last night I went back to S3, now my app is back to working again. I'm still unclear why but the Cloudinary Gem when used with my Bootstrap setup the app breaks in production.

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting when you have commented out the application.css file?

Comment: its the same error. If I remove <%=stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" it works.

Comment: The error (Invalid CSS after...) is app/assets/stylesheets/application.css. Try to rename the file to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.less

Comment: I tried this as well and no change, same issue, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tracked down this error, It was the invalid css.

```
  font-family: 'Myriad W01 Lt It';
```